# the task of the new clicker should be with the sum of all the previous ones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

There is a task! It is necessary to create a new clicker by clicking on the button, which will be created with a value equal to the sum of all previous clickers (if there are clickers with a value of 3 and 5, the next one should be created with a value of 8). At the moment, I'm stuck on the problem that when creating a new clicker, the value of the previous one is stored in the volume. Tell me how to solve the problem? (Yes, and according to the condition, every fourth component should not be a clicker, but a timer)

```
function App() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState([]);

  function addClicker() {
    setClick([...click, <Counter />]);
  }

  function del() {
    setClick([...click.slice(0, click.length - 1)]);
  }

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <AddDelButton />
      <button className='btn'  onClick={addClicker}>addClicker</button>
      <button className='btn' onClick={del}>delClicker</button>
      {click.map((item, i) =>
        !((i + 1) % 4) ? <NoClicker key={i} /> : <Counter props={click} key={i} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

////

function Counter(props) {
  const State = useSelector((state) => state.ourState.count);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log('====>>>', State);


  return (
    <div className='counter'>
      <button className='btnClick'
        onClick={() => dispatch(incrementValue())}
      >
        Increment
      </button>
      <h2>{State}</h2>
      <button className='btnClick'
        onClick={() => dispatch(decrementValue())}
      >
        Decrement
      </button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is not working with your current code and what issue are you facing specifically? Please create a [mre] of your issue so we can clearly see the problem. Storing JSX in state is often not a good idea, as it can lead to issues with stale state and other unexpected issues.

Comment: When a new clicker is created, the state of the previous one is saved in the new component instance. The task is that the next created component (clicker) contains the numerical value of the previous clicker.

Comment: You need to add unique `key`s to your clickers, otherwise React cannot distinguish them.